# Isomorphism of Associated Graded Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two filtered associative $k$-algebras with increasing filtrations $F^{\bullet}$ and $G^{\bullet}$, respectively. It is safe to assume that the filtrations are exhaustive. Assume that there is a filtered algebra morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$, that is, f satisfies $f(F^n)\subseteq G^n$. If the induced map $gr(f): gr_{F^{\bullet}}(A)\rightarrow gr_{G^{\bullet}}(B)$ is an isomorphism of graded $k$-algebras, is it true that the original map $f$ is also a $k$-algebra isomorphism. If not, under what conditions would that be true? Thank you for your help and feedback.

Comment: I was reading the very last line of the proof of Proposition 5.3 in Gaitsgory's notes in Geometric Representation Theory: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/267y/catO.pdf (page 27)                                             He is making this type of argument there.

Comment: I haven't read it yet, but it seems in your text the algebras a very special, e.g., $gr(A)$ is commutative.

Comment: Thank you for your useful feedback. What you say seems correct. Indeed, Gaitsgory works with the sheaf of differential operators on some algebraic variety. Its associated graded algebra is, as you suggest, commutative. Do you have a proof in mind for that spacial case?I cannot think of a good argument why that should be true even when $gr(A)$ and $gr(B)$ are commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another proof, which is basically the same proof as last time, but references the Five lemma.

> **Lemma.** For the map $f: A \to B$, if the induced map $$gr^{\leq p}_F(A) \to gr^{\leq p}_G(B)$$ is an isomorphism then $F^iA \to F^iB$ is an isomorphism for $i \leq p$.

*Proof.* If $p=0$ the $gr^0_F(A) = F^0A, gr^0_GB = G^0B$ so there is nothing to prove. Now assume $F^{p-1}A \to F^{p-1}B$ is an isomorphism. We have a morphism between exact sequences:

$0 \to F^{p-1}A \to F^pA \to gr_F^p(A) \to 0$

$0 \to G^{p-1}B \to G^pB \to gr_G^p(B) \to 0$

Where all the arrows except the middle we know are isomorphisms. By the five lemma, the middle is an isomorphism, too. $\square$

Now we know $F^iA \to G^iB$ is an isomorphism for all $i$, and hence that $$\bigcup F^iA \to \bigcup G^iB$$ is an isomorphism. So long as the filtrations are exhaustive, we're done.

Comment: Ben Dyer, does the Lemma in your answer depend on the ground ring?  Meaning if the ground ring $k$ is not a field but some commutative ring like, say, the polynomial ring $\mathbb C[t]$, does your proof go through? As far as I can say, as long as the filtration is exhaustive, the proof goes through. But I wanted to clarify this detail.

Comment: Also, in your proof you are only concerned with the module structure over $k$, right? The map $f$ in your Lemma is a homomorphism of $k$-modules, it is not assumed to be an algebra map, right?

Comment: How does the proof with the $5$ Lemma change when the filtrations of $A$ and $B$ are decreasing? Do you need then completeness of the filtration of $B$?

Comment: This proof doesn’t work for decreasing filtrations, there is no analog of the $p=0$ case. For decreasing filtrations you need completeness of $A$ like in the other answer so that the infinite sum $\sum x_i$ is well-defined

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last clarification: the proof involving the Five Lemma (in your second answer) in the case of increasing filtrations of the algebras remains the same if the given algebras $A$ and $B$ are defined not over a field but over an unfiltered commutative base ring $R$, right? We do not need to restrict ourselves to associative algebras over fields, I think.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius Yeah this only relies on $A$ and $B$ being filtered abelian groups, so anything that has an underlying abelian group with additional structure is fine too.

Comment: Thanks, Ben Dyer.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to assume the filtrations are exhaustive.

---

I'll use a bar to denote the associated graded, e.g. $\bar f = gr(f)$, $\bar A^k = F^kA/F^{k-1}A$ and if $y \in G^kB\setminus G^{k-1}B$ then $\bar y \in \bar B^k$. (It would have been better notation to have defined $\pi_{k}: F^kA \to F^kA/F^{k-1}A$ and kept track of $k$.)

**Injectivity:**
Assume $\bar f$ is an isomorphism. Let $x \in A$ and take the minimal $k$ such that $x \in F^kA$. Then $\bar x \in \bar A^k$ is nonzero, so $\bar f(\bar x) \neq 0$. But $\bar f(\bar x) = \overline{f(x)}$ so this means $f(x) \neq 0$.

*Note.* It's important that $\bigcup F^kA = A$, otherwise we can't find a minimal such $k$ (the set of $k$ with $x \in F^kA$ may be empty).

**Surjectivity:**
Let $y \in G^kB$ for minimal $k$ and $\bar y \in \bar B^k$ the corresponding element. Take a preimage $\bar x \in \bar A^k$ and lift this to $x \in F^kA$. We can't say that $f(x) = y$, but at least $y_1 := y - f(x) \in G^{k-1}B$. Now we repeat for $y_1$ and find $x_1$ such that $y_1 - f(x_1) \in G^{k-2}B$. And so on until $k-i = 0$ and we can find a preimage $x + x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{k-1}$.

*Note.* It's important that $\bigcup G^kB = B$, else we can't find a minimal $k$ again.

—

Added:

In the case of decreasing sequences, I think you can prove injectivity the same way but you need to assume $\bigcap F^kA=0$. For surjectivity you need to assume completeness with respect to the $G$ filtration so that the infinite sum makes sense and probably also the intersection condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I think you assume in your answer that the filtrations are increasing, not decreasing. Exhaustiveness is a reasonable assumption. Dietrich Burde suggested that maybe the underlying rings $gr(A)$ and $gr(B)$ should be commutative. Your proof does not rely on such an assumption, it seems.

Comment: Exhaustiveness goes usually with an increasing filtration, not with a decreasing filtration. Could you clarify that. Was "decreasing" a mistake, or do you use it somewhere in your proof? I think you work with an increasing filtrations I will edit my question to account for that.

Comment: The question says increasing. Did you mean decreasing? Or do I have it backwards?

Comment: Indeed, the question says "increasing", but you said in your comment that you've "mostly thought about decreasing filtrations". I was perplexed a bit, so I decided to ask.

Comment: Oh I understand. I meant “in the past i have mostly thought about decreasing things, so its possible i made a dumb mistake trying to think about increasing things”

Comment: So Please ignore anything about decreasing sequences, the main part is about increasing ones.